# OSGI aware IDE at development time

Tags: ide, osgi

I'm starting development using OSGi but when one of my concerns is about the lack of support at development time, meaning that commonly IDEs ([started using Intellij IDEA](http://the-dailynerd.blogspot.com/2013/11/not-developing-osgi-applications-with.html)) don't use OSGi for class discovery but classpath search IDE managed (**I'm in search for one that uses OSGi instead**).

The main concern here is to prevent classpath issues at execution time by suing the same OSGi  mechanisms at development time.

Does any IDE work this way ?

update: added link to blog post with my experience with IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSGi is a runtime technology, therefore there is no such thing as an OSGi mechanism at build time. Also bear in mind that ultimately all Java code must be compiled by a Java compiler, usually javac. The javac compiler does not use package dependencies like `Import-Package`, it always uses JARs or directories on the classpath.

Having said that, [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org) uses package filtering at build time, based on the exported and private packages of the dependencies. This is a special feature of Eclipse and it does not work when you compile outside of the IDE, e.g. with Ant or Maven. However it may still be useful because if you try to use a non-exported package from another bundle you will get a problem marker with a red X in the Eclipse IDE.